# How can I make a http file upload server with nodejs? not using form

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, file-upload, server

I want to make a http file upload server with nodejs, not using form.
I've seen many fileupload examples with `form`.
But I need a server code that can receive files when called by api format.

For example,

Server side is `nodejs` (What I'm curious)

Client side is `javascript`(XmlHttpRequest), `C#`, `python`,.... whatever.

When client called api for fileupload, to receive files at server side, how can I do?

Comment: you should add some source code attempt to question

Comment: Do you mean you want Node.js code that can handle file update request? And as the request is not using form, what's that? Can you show some client code?

Answer (score 0):

Use FormData.

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append("username", "Groucho");
formData.append("accountnum", 123456); // number 123456 is immediately converted to a string "123456"

// HTML file input, chosen by user
formData.append("userfile", fileInputElement.files[0]);

// JavaScript file-like object
var content = '<a id="a"><b id="b">hey!</b></a>'; // the body of the new file...
var blob = new Blob([content], { type: "text/xml"});

formData.append("webmasterfile", blob);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "http://foo.com/submitform.php");
request.send(formData);
```

See more from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: Thank you, @Pine Tree. But I need a server side code.

Comment: Check this to see if it would help: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/file-upload-with-multer-in-node--cms-32088

Comment: This is also "form" :)